# Float:Left is not removed with media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using Float in my CSS, but I want to cancel it if the user is on a small screen.
My CSS with media query works fine, except that the "float:left" property is still applied, even after stating that it should not be used:

```
/* floating some buttons */
#n2, #n3 {
  float:right;
}

/* but this is not removing the float: */
@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 780px) {
  #n2, #n3 {
    clear: both !important;
  }
}
```

How can I apply "float" only in certain circumstances?

Comment: You need to use `float: none` instead.

Comment: Where are you removing it, I can't see that anywhere, clearing the floats isn't the same as resetting the float property.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of "float:none" !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I noted in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680301/floatleft-is-not-removed-with-media-query#comment32773734_21680301), when you're going to remove the `float`, you need to set the value to `none`:

```css
/* but this is not removing the float: */
@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 780px) {
  #n2, #n3 {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/pipik/1/edit)**

Answer (score 6):

**Answer
:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 780px) {
      #n2, #n3 {
        float:none;
      }
    }
```

**Explanation:**

You need to set the `float:none` to reset the `float:left`